# How do I make date fields read only

Tags: 2007, edit-form, read-only

I have two date fields that I need my end users to see but not modify.  How can I achieve this in the best manner?   I am not very versed in code so any detailed ideas you can provide would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Dynamic Forms](http://spjsblog.com/2013/08/12/dynamic-forms-for-sharepoint-v3/) by Alexander Bautz. It consists in modifying the Edit Form WebPart and adding a Content Editor Web Part to add the Javascript Code. I have tried it in SharePoint 2013 and it works well.

To edit the form web part use the ribbon of the Tasks Lists or SharePoint Designer [image]

Comment: I am on Sharepoint 2007.  Can I use this on that level?

Comment: Yes. In SharePoint 2007 go to EditForm and insert toolpaneview=2 behind the URL in this format:
…/EditForm.aspx?ID=[an existing id from your list]&toolpaneview=2

Press Enter and you should be able to add a CEWP to the page.

Answer (score 0):

By default there isn't a way to make a field read only if users have permission to modify the list.

There are a few code options however but if you want to avoid that path then the only solution I can think of is running two task lists and create the read only fields as a lookup from one list to the other.

This guide from MS might be of use [List lookup columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA101729901.aspx#_Toc270607415)

Comment: Sorry about that - it is in a task list.  They need to be able to modify some of the fields in the task but not all of them.  So, basically need to make specific fields read only.

Comment: How do I do the two task lists option?

Comment: Is there a relatively simple code option I can use?  I am good at following directions :)

Comment: I can't get the lookup to look up a date field.  It does not show the date field as an option to choose.